# instead of innerText, innerHTML get specific sub-elements of querySelectorAll

Tags: javascript, node.js, web-scraping, puppeteer, playwright

In both cases, I get the html but want the url from within the column loop not the html as a string.
For example:
`<img src="../uploads/spooky/26785.jpg" data-src="../uploads/spooky/26785.jpg" class="Foo">`
should be => `'../uploads/spooky/2687.jpg'`

```
 const result = await page.$$eval('table tr.GridCell', rows => {
   return Array.from(rows, row => {
   const columns = row.querySelectorAll('td');
   return Array.from(columns, (column,i) => {
    if(i==2){
        // want src
        return column.innerHTML;
    }
    if (i==14 || i ==15){
        //want url
        return {name: column.innerText, url: column.innerHTML}
    }
    return column.innerText});
 });
});
```

Comment: Where is the URL in that TD?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If I understand correctly, you need `column.querySelector('img.Foo').getAttribute('src')` instead of `column.innerHTML`.